# How to change Local Host to Server

Tags: mysql, vb.net, visual-studio

How can i change local host to a specific server my code is from vb and I need to access only one server over the network.

Here is my code

```
Sub OpenServer()
    conn = New MySqlConnection
    conn.ConnectionString = "server=localhost;userid=root;password=; database=bptest;Convert Zero Datetime=True"
    conn.Open()
End Sub
```

Comment: It is not clear if your requirement is to change the connectionstring dynamically in code, can you explain it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the server's IP instead of localhost, and also edit the userid and password to your userid and password as configured on your server

```
Sub OpenServer()
    conn = New MySqlConnection
    conn.ConnectionString = "server=127.0.0.1;userid=root;password=; database=bptest;Convert Zero Datetime=True"
    conn.Open()
End Sub
```

If you can't connect it might be permissions and you'll have to update those using a `GRANT` like so:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON databasename.* TO 'USERNAME'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'PASSWORD' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Replace `databasename` with your database's name, replace `USERNAME` with your username (in your case 'root'), replace '%' with your IP if you want to restrict access (% means any ip), replace 'PASSWORD' with your password.

Sidenote, if your user isn't supposed to have all privileges, just edit the 'ALL PRIVILEGES' with whatever privileges your user is supposed to have.

Comment: Is your user allowed to connect from your IP address? You need to run a GRANT query on your user @ your machine's IP address, I'll update my answer in a second